# How secure is Java RMI in the Internet?

Tags: java, security, protocols, rmi

For many protocols it's not recommendable to use them in the Internet. What about Java RMI?

Comment: How secure do you need it to be?

Comment: [Java RMI with SSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/SSLInfo.html)

Comment: The most important aspect for me is the degree of exploitability.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Thanks, that would be a good opportunity but I could use SSL/TLS for (almost) every protocol. What do you think about the security of the protocol itself?

Comment: If it doesn't encrypt traffic, then it's open to sniffing, replay, man-in-the-middle, you name it.

Comment: Sniffing ok, man-in-the-middle ok, but replay? Isn't there a sequence number or the like?

Comment: Do you know about any RMI security papers? E.g. a penetration test report?

Comment: Java RMI's security is no different from any other protocol's. If you don't use SSL it isn't secure.

Comment: You could actually plugin your own encryption into the pipe. You'd have to supply your SocketFactory, but its achievable. You could also devise a chain, so your custom encryption, chained with SSL